# java 8 unique keyset from set of maps is slow using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

Can anyone tell me why using the java 8 stream/lambda is so much slower than a for each loop in the code below?

```
Set<Map<Path, String>> set = new HashSet<>();
Map<Path, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put(Paths.get("foo"), "bar");
set.add(map1);

Map<Path, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put(Paths.get("foo"), "ham");
set.add(map2);

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Set<Path> uniqueFromStream = set.stream().flatMap(m -> m.keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.err.println("miliseconds for streams: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Set<Path> uniqueFromLoop = new HashSet<>();
for(final Map<Path,String> map : set){
  uniqueFromLoop.addAll(map.keySet());
}
System.err.println("miliseconds for loops: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

when I run it, on average the streams/lambda is 63 miliseconds, but the for each loop is 0 miliseconds!

Comment: lambdas and `Stream`s were added to support parallelization on large sets of objects.  However, it is very inefficient serially accessing and modifying small sets of data. If you want to try it with parallel support, replace `.stream()` with `.parallelStream()`

Comment: There's also the problem of classloading taking time, that this example does not consider. A lot more has to be loaded for the streams.

Comment: You only test an each method once, which does not really make a good benchmark. 

At very least you should try to measure this in a loop (i.e. 1000 times), to reduce the influence of JIT, class-loading and zillion other things like that.

Or (better), use a specialized micro-benchmarking framework, like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Otherwise what you observe on a single test run can not be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

Primitives loops will always be more efficient than lambdas, especially on small collections because it's more "native".

On the other side, lambdas explains more the intention of the developer with functional programming and your code is more maintenable.

Lambdas will be more and more efficient with time and if you use it on large collections and in parallel.

There was a interesting speech at Devoxx Belgium By Trisha Gee on this subject : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlzMV83RTtw

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no magic.

Stream processing takes a small bit of time to initialize, and makes it harder for the compiler to optimize the code. Lambdas invocations add an overhead. And of course, you "pay" for the collection step (`Collectors.toSet()`) at the end.

On the other hand, for loops are simpler, and aggressively optimized/inlined by the compiler.

Comment: With only 1 iteration, I don't the JIT would do anything, so there is no optimization here afaik.

Comment: I was talking about the java compiler (static) optimizations. Bytecode level, not native.

Comment: There no/very limited bytecode optimization, that would go against the idea of a having a JIT in the first place.

Comment: @Jorn, Here is some food for thought for you : https://briangordon.github.io/2014/01/javac-optimizations.html

Comment: The article that you linked has very basic things, like constant folding, but the real stuff, (e.g. loop un-roling)  is left to the JIT, as the article mentions at the bottom.

Comment: I *never said* JIT didn't optimize the bytecode! The "basic stuff" doesn't mean it's irrelevant to performance...